# Matching 2 sets of Data with 2 requirements

Tags: vba, excel

I have this problem right here. I want to match and highlight these two data from table 1 and table 2. The criteria are the contract code must match and so should the sum lots quantity for that contract code in table 2.

For example in table 1 `ZBZ8        375` should match and highlight with the three data entries on table 2 `50      ZBZ8` `125      ZBZ8` `200      ZBZ8`.

```
Table 1    
CONTRACT    LOTS
    ZBZ8        375 
    ZBU8        339 
    ZBM8       -250 
    ZBH8        -75 
Table 2
    Qty    Contract
    40      TYZ7
    200     TYZ7C
    -400    TYZ7C
    100     EDZ7
    100     EDZ7
    100     EDZ7
    100     EDH8
    -100    EDZ8
    -100    EDZ8
    -100    EDH9
    -25     ZBH8
    -50     ZBH8
    -250    ZBM8
    114     ZBU8
    200     ZBU8
    25      ZBU8
    50      ZBZ8
    125     ZBZ8
    200     ZBZ8
    25      XMZ7
    -115    YMZ7
    -200    YMZ7
```

I am very new to VBA, please be patient with me. I have done some research, and it appears Dictionary is the way to go about this?

I have gotten the following code, but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
Public Sub CheckTotal()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")             ' change as appropriate e.g. "Futures - DB"

    Dim totalsDict As Scripting.Dictionary       'set reference to microsoft scripting runtime

    Set totalsDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim valuesArr()
    Dim valuesSource As Range

    Set valuesSource = ws.Range("A2:B6")         'range containing values to sum
    valuesArr = valuesSource.Value

    Dim code As Long

    For code = LBound(valuesArr, 1) To UBound(valuesArr, 1)

        If totalsDict.Exists(valuesArr(code, 2)) Then 'if code exists add new value to existing value otherwise add code and value to the dictionary e.g. TYZ7C ,200    


            totalsDict(valuesArr(code, 2)) = totalsDict(valuesArr(code, 2)) + valuesArr(code, 1)

        Else

            totalsDict.Add valuesArr(code, 2), valuesArr(code, 1)

        End If

    Next code

    Dim currCell As Range
    Dim loopRange As Range

    Set loopRange = ws.Range("D2:D3")            'range containing codes whose sums are to be checked

    Dim colourCodesArr()
    ReDim colourCodesArr(0 To loopRange.Rows.Count)
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 0

    For Each currCell In loopRange.Cells

        If currCell.Offset(, 1) = totalsDict(currCell.Value2) Then

            currCell.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

            colourCodesArr(counter) = currCell   'store codes whose totals  match summing of rows match in array

            counter = counter + 1

        Else

            currCell.Offset(, 1).Font.Color = vbRed

        End If

    Next currCell

    ReDim Preserve colourCodesArr(0 To counter - 1)

    For Each currCell In valuesSource.Columns(2).Rows 'Loop the codes in the source range checking if a no match was registered

        If UBound(Filter(colourCodesArr, currCell.Value2)) = -1 Then 'if code not found in array highlight in red

            currCell.Offset(, -1).Font.Color = vbRed

        Else

            currCell.Offset(, -1).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

        End If

    Next currCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't seem to have added the "the following code".

Comment: Sorry undeadherbs, i have added it on.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error and on which line? Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't going to get you anywhere.